# PHP move_uploaded_file permission denied though it seems it should

Tags: apache, file-upload, php

I am learning PHP and trying to upload a file using this code :

```
$destination = "uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $destination);
```

but I am faced with

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

I can change the permissions for the "uploads" directory to be writable by everybody, but of course this is bad practice.
The folder permissions are :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 loai loai 4096 Dec 30 12:44 uploads
```

and running `ps aux | grep httpd` yields

```
loai      6728  0.0  0.0   4368   832 pts/1    S+   18:37   0:00 grep --colour=auto httpd
```

so shouldn't the apache process be able to write in the given directory ?
Thanks

Comment: The working directory of the PHP process may not be what you think it is.

Comment: Your script is wide-open to directory traversal and remote script injection attacks. Keep in mind that everything that comes from the user could contain malicous data, including the `name` field of the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: Ohters than loai don't have write access to the directory. Please review the access rights.

Comment: Your `ps` output only shows your `grep` process, not `apache`.

Comment: do **NOT** use the `['name']` parameter, unless you really want your server pwn3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as noted in comments to the question, your `ps` output is showing the `grep` process itself, not `httpd` process (or whatever your web server is). So that probably means that your web server is running as a different user, not as `loai`. Either change ownership of the `uploads` folder or make it group-writable and then add web server's user to the appropriate group

Comment: but how to know the web server user ? I am running it on my own machine.

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba It should be in a configuration file. If you use apache, open up `/etc/apache/apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache/httpd.conf`, and search for a line which begins from `User`, usually it's something like `User www-data`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using full path for destination. Something like:

```
/var/www/project/uploads
```

Comment: thanks guys, I guess the correct reason is by Barmar, I thought ps showed that the apache process is owned by loai, but then, who owns the apache process ? or it is launched as an independent user?

Answer (score 0):

If you can read from that dir with relative path, then just chown it:

```
cd $path_to_your_site_root
chown -R loai:loai uploads
```